# Prove that $g(x)=e^{-x^2}$ has a unique fixed point on the interval [0,1]

Tags: numerical-methods

Hello I need help with this question,

Prove that $g(x)=e^{-x^2}$ has a unique fixed point on the interval [0,1]

Comment: Are you familiar with derivatives?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The continuous function $f(x) = e^{-x^2} - x$ is positive at 0 and negative at 1, so by the Intermediate Value Theorem there is a point $a \in [0,1]$ with $e^{-a^2} - a = 0$ or $e^{-a^2} = a$. This fixed point is unique because $e^{-x^2}$ is monotonically decreasing on $[0,1]$.

Comment: how can I show that f(x) is monotonically decreasing on the interval? (without graph)

Comment: $-x$ is decreasing, so it would suffice to show that so is $e^{-x^2}$. Indeed, $e^{-x^2}-e^{-y^2} = e^{-x^2}(1-e^{x^2-y^2}) = e^{-x^2}(1-e^{(x-y)(x+y)})$, which is positive iff $(x-y)(x+y)<0$, i.e. iff $x<y$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** This is tantamount to showing that the function $h(x):=e^{-x^2}-x$ has a unique root on $[0,1]$.

Note that $h(0)=1$ and $h(1)=\frac{1}{e}-1<0$. The function is continuous, so it must cross the axis at least once.  Does it happen to be the case that $h$ is either strictly monotone increasing or strictly monotone decreasing?  That would do it.  (Why?)